# Least bad way to sleep in a Django view

Tags: python, django

I have a synchronous API in Django that makes multiple external requests. For performance reason, I'll depreciate it and switch to an asynchronous model: the request will trigger multiple celery sub-tasks and the client will have to fetch the task status until it is completed.

However I cannot get rid of the existing API right away as we need to enforce backward compatibility. For this to work, I intend to implement a synchronous wrapper around my asynchronous tasks. This is what the backward compatible API must do in my opinion:

- launch the asynchronous tasks
- sleep
- refresh the object, exit if it's completed
- or loop

Something along the lines of :

```py
task = MyTask.objects.create(...).run() # Will span multiple parallel sub-tasks
while task.is_ongoing(): # Check if all sub-tasks are completed
    sleep(1)
    task.refresh_from_db()
```

Of course it's very bad design to sleep in Django's view but I don't think there is another way to ensure backward compatibility with my synchronous API. If Django did support `async` things would be better but I haven't found a way to suspend current thread without blocking everything. 
Of course I could run all tasks synchronously in the synchronous API but it'd defeat the purpose of parallelizing "long-running" tasks (a few seconds each).

Hence my two questions:

- is there another way?
- what's the least bad way of sleeping in Django's main thread? Is it `sleep` or are there slightly better options?

Comment: I think this is more suitable for code review?

Answer (score 1):

One better way than `sleep` and a loop is to use [`Task.apply`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.apply) to trigger celery tasks rather than `apply_async`. `apply` will block until a task completes.

Comment: In that case each sub-task will execute sequentially and I'll lose the benefit of running them in parallel using celery workers. But going in this direction, it looks like using a [`Group`](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#groups) to run tasks with `Group.apply_async` then block until they are done with `Group.get` could work.